Set theory question about the existance of a certain set
I need to show that given some (possibly infinite) family of sets that are non-empty and not pairwise-disjoint there exists a set that has exactly one element in common with each of these given sets.
I'm sure I need to show this in ZC (as F was taught a bit after we were given the assignment).
I tried playing around with sub-sets of the given family of sets and didn't make any progress.
Intuitively I would like to show this inductively but the family might not be countable.
I could look at the set of sets containing each element and maybe move inductively on the sizes of these sets but I think I need to do so from the largest to the smallest and I can't as I don't believe a maximum size exists necessarily.
Any help would be appreciated as I'm quite lost.

This is false, see the family ${{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,0}}$.

The set {0,2} mets thee requirements. I meant the set exists not in the sense its part of the family of sets, but in the general sense. Thanks for the help

${2,0}$ does not have exactly one element in common with ${2,0}$, because it has $2$.

Oh sorry.  You are correct ofcourse and this is a typo in the exercise given to me. thanks alot!
